# vb6 ODBC Connection or Custom API?

Tags: vb6

I have a vb6 application that uses a Database MS Access in read-only method.

I want to change this database with another, centralized and server side like SQL Server or MySQL.

Actually, into vb6 I use DAO for the connection (I know is an older method and there are better like ADO)

I don't know if is better to create my own API and connect to the data by vb6 or buy a SQL SERVER Cloud (Ex: azure) and connect them by ODBC Connection.
I'm afraid that this connection might be too slow...

What do you advise me to do?

The DB is 5MB of dimension with 500/600 connection every day

Comment: Why not use DAO or ADO to connect to SQL Server?  Or even [Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45491667/5162073) for that matter?

Comment: If your Access database is already defined, and the table definitions match those of the SQL Serverf database, you can just create identically-named links in the Access database to the SQL Server tables to replace the existing local tables, and make no changes at all to the VB code.

Comment: DAO is an older method, and has its disadvantages for sure.  However, for a single-user application, it's often considerably faster, especially for queries that access linked tables - such as the method I described above.

Comment: Unless you know for a fact that performance is a problem (maybe it already is a problem) then I don't think I would factor that into this decision. Instead I would start with the simplest approach that would work, and that would require the fewest changes.

Comment: I don't know anyone can answer it for you 100%, as it is application-specific.  What you can do is make some strategic investigations to get some hard data and come to a decision.  Try setting up a "freemium" cloud db and connecting.  If acceptable, try setting up temp free edition of another server and seeing what types of latency you get.  Phrases that start with "I'm afraid that..." are just that.  They are fears, and you need hard data.  Weigh that with business concerns, and once you've done that, theoretically, your decision should make itself.